# I have a problem when running Android I get this : error Failed to launch emulator. Reason

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have a problem when running Android I get this error :
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
I did all the solutions that I read from this site and it was not useful
Please Help!
[image]

Comment: sounds you have issue in react native installation especially in environments variables if so, follow this guide for success installation in windows https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: Did you run the emulator using AVD manager in Android Studio before running the project ? If not please make sure to turn on the emulator